# Refresh page with Ajax without jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I need to update my page automatically without refreshing it with Ajax. But so far I have seen is that people use jQuery and PHP, and I'm not that good at coding. So what I need to do is to add Ajax to HTML without adding PHP or jQuery. 
Pages where I found something similar, but all of them uses jQuery:
[ajax jquery update page without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259008/ajax-jquery-update-page-without-refreshing)
[Update data on a page without refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577457/update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing)
http://api.jquery.com/load/
Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an AJAX call without jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery)

Comment: If you are going to use ajax and you are not good at coding, then use jquery.

Comment: It's better if you try it with jquery... It's not this difficoult...

Comment: Could someone explain how jquery works? Because how I understood is that you can not add jquery right to html, and I need to do

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>        
    setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); },5000);
</script>
```

Put this snippet in your desired HTML page. This setInterval() function refresh the page every 5 second.

Comment: setInterval don't has sense if you make the page reload. It should be setTimeout. Also, if you have a slow connection/busy server and it lasts more than 5 seconds to reload the page, setInterval will keep restarting the reload, without even reloading.